# Question regarding Horizontal shrink and Horizontal Stretch

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know the property of Horizontal shrink is $y=f(cx)$ where $ c>1$ and we need to divide the $x$ coordinates by the factor.

Horizontal Stretch is $y=f(cx)$ where $0<c<1$ and we also need to divide the $x$ coordinates by the factor.

IHere I have a question i'm trying to find:  $f(x)= -x+5$; horizontal shrink by  a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ The answer to that is $f(x)=-2x+5$.

Comment: The coefficient of $x$ is $-1$.  Replacing $x$ by $-x$ is a reflection in the $y$-axis since it sends the point $(a, b)$ to the point $(-a, b)$.

Comment: But i'm talking about it being a horizontal shrink or stretch, since the factor is between 0 and 1, shouldn't it be a stretch?

Comment: The only factor I see is $-1$.  Where did you get the number $1/2$?

Comment: For $f(x)=-x+5$, there is no stretch or shrink from the parent function of $f(x)=x$

Comment: the question i'm trying to solve goes like this. $f(x)=-x+5$; horizontal shrink by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$. The answer is $|-2x+5|$, and I know how they got the answer but shouldn't it be called a stretch since it's between 0 and 1?

Comment: Oh, that is your question.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the context in your most recent comment.  Otherwise, it is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Horizontal Shrink $=$ Vertical Stretch

So, when they ask you to shrink the function horizontally by a factor of $\frac 12$, you can think of it as stretching the function by a factor of $2$. Using this, you can say that $f(x)=-x+5$, when horizontally shrunk/vertically stretched becomes $|-2x+5|$.

Also, the question:

> What is new function after $f(x)=-x+5$ is horizontally shrunk by a factor of $\frac 12$?

is unclear. This is because shrunk by a factor of $\frac 12$ can also mean stretched by a factor of $2$. However, in most cases, horizontally shrunk by a factor of $\frac 12$ will mean the same thing as horizontally shrunk by a factor of $2$.

Comment: Yeah I just realized my mistake, the wording of the question was throwing it off, thanks.